# UIActionSheet on iPad frame too small

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am trying to display a `UIActionSheet` on the iPad with a `UIPickerView` in it, I have the equivalent code working for iPhone so my `UIPickerView` delegate and datasource stuff work, but on the iPad when I use `-[UIActionSheet showFromRect:inView:animated:]` the result `UIPopover`/`UIActionSheet` is way too small and I can not seem to set the frame size, also none of the buttons are displayed.

I don't know if this is because they are outside the bounds or there is something else going on. This is what my code looks like after I have removed all non-essential code (iPhone etc). Does anybody know what I am doing wrong, does anybody know of any examples.

```
CGRect thePickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 485.0);
UIPickerView * thePickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:thePickerFrame];

[pickerActionSheet release], pickerActionSheet =
        [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose" delegate:self 
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                               destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                               otherButtonTitles:@"Next", nil];
thePickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
thePickerView.dataSource = self;
thePickerView.delegate = self;

[pickerActionSheet addSubview:thePickerView];
[thePickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
[thePickerView release];

[pickerActionSheet showFromRect:currentTextField.bounds
                             inView:currentTextField animated:NO];
pickerActionSheet.frame = thePickerFrame;
```

Comment: I just did a little experimenting to see when - [UIActionSheet  setFrame:] is being called. I seems after the event loop where the above is called another event loop initiated by iOS result in - [UIActionSheet  setFrame:] being called with the small frame that is displayed.

Comment: Aren't you better off with popover on iPad with this functionality? AFAIK ActionSheet is for buttons only.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think that UIActionSheet is not resizable, try to comment in your code the line with `[pickerActionSheet addSubview:thePickerView];` and you will see that the ActionSheet fits perfecly to the buttons.

I would recommend a `UIPopoverController` with a custom `UIViewController`. Something like this:

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;

UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(BACK_ACTION:)];
UIBarButtonItem *chooseButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Choose" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Next" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(NEXT_ACTION:)];
UIBarButtonItem *fixed1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *fixed2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

[toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:cancelButton, fixed1, chooseButton, fixed2, nextButton, nil]];

UIPickerView    *thePickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 216)];
CGRect thePickerFrame = thePickerView.frame;
thePickerFrame.origin.y = toolbar.frame.size.height;
[thePickerView setFrame:thePickerFrame];


UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] init];
[view addSubview:thePickerView];
[view addSubview:toolbar];

UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[vc setView:view];
[vc setContentSizeForViewInPopover:CGSizeMake(320, 260)];

popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:vc];

thePickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
thePickerView.dataSource = self;
thePickerView.delegate = self;

[thePickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:NO];

[popover presentPopoverFromRect:currentTextField.bounds inView:currentTextField permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Where popover is a class variable declared in .h (`UIPopoverController *popover;`).

By the way, I'm using ARC, so there is no release in the code.

Answer (score 8):

I managed to make it work using a silly way.

**For your reference:**

Setup PickerView. 

**UIActionSheet's** width can't be adjusted somehow, so have to adjust pickerView accordingly.  Height wise, you can adjust with the amount of **"\n"** in actionSheet title.

```
UIDatePicker * pickerView = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 270, 220)];
pickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate; 

UIActionSheet * actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];    

[actionSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];
[actionSheet addSubview:pickerView];
[actionSheet showFromRect:button.frame inView:button.superview animated:YES];
[actionSheet release];
```

Set Frame or Bound doesn't work for me.

```
[actionSheet setBounds:pickerView.frame];   
[actionSheet setFrame:pickerView.frame];
```

Agreed on using UIPopoverController, but don't know why, it got a serious UI delay when I put UIDatePickerView into popover (it took almost 1 sec lag to pop up) which I can't find the root cause.  So have to fallback to above method.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Although hacky, this is at least easy to implement in a universal app. Thanks!