# iPad UIActionSheet size issue

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uidatepicker, uiactionsheet

I have searched and cannot find an answer to my problem.

I am using the following code to popup a `UIDatePicker` when entering a `UITextField`. It works perfectly on iPhone.

```
mySheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
[mySheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0);

UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
[datePicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeTime];

if (whatPressed == 1) {
    [datePicker setDate:startDate];
}
else
{
    [datePicker setDate:endDate];
}


[mySheet addSubview:datePicker];

UIToolbar *controlToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, mySheet.bounds.size.width, 44)];
[controlToolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
[controlToolBar sizeToFit];

UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
UIBarButtonItem *setButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Set" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dismissDate)];
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelDate)];

[controlToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, cancelButton, setButton, nil] animated:NO];
[mySheet addSubview:controlToolBar];

[mySheet showInView:self.view];

[mySheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
```

I am now trying to use the same code for the iPad version and the view appears but it is not high enough. I have tried changing the `CGRect` values but they don't seem to have any effect.

The view appears to be the width of an iPhone, and about 1cm in height. Confused.

Help appreciated.

Comment: The method `showFromRect:inView:animated:` is a better choice for the iPad.

Comment: Thanks @KevinGrant I'll give that a go and get back to you

Comment: I tried numerous methods to display this UIDatePicker. In the end I have given up and used the iPad's large screen to display the UIDatePicker directly. Thanks anyway ... this is very strange behaviour though and I hope someone knows a fix

Comment: I am also stuck in this Problem

Comment: I too have this, anyone find a solution?

Comment: Same issue here. I ended up having to scrap the idea of a UIActionSheet and went with a UIPopoverController. I have a UIViewController with a UIDatePicker and UIButton as its subviews and it has the same outcome I was looking for.

Comment: Anyone brought this up on Apple Support/Community? Also, found this workaround: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7974475/uiactionsheet-on-ipad-frame-too-small